# program mouse right-click so that when I press it twice, it acts as if i pressed it once

Tags: drivers, mouse, macros

I have no idea where to even start with this...

I recently brought a new gaming mouse which is fully programmable. Sometimes, my finger will twitch and press the right-hand button without me wanting, bringing up the context menu. it's really annoying.

Anyway, I have an option to program my mouse using macros in the software. Is there a way to use a macro to make a right-hand button click only register if I press it two/three times? (I still need to use the left-hand button normally, I just want it to register the right-hand button as if I pressed it once but I am actually pressing it two/three times.)

I am using the Pictek wired gaming mouse and running its software.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will ignore a right-click if it doesn't follow
a previous right-click within 400 milliseconds:

```
#Persistent                     ; stay resident
Hotkey, RButton, PreventSingleRightClick
Return
PreventSingleRightClick:
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400) ; second click
        MouseClick, Right       ; send the right-click
        Return
    }
Return                          ; ignore single click
```

Note that a third right-click will also be passed on, as well as all following
right-clicks, so it's best to avoid doing that (or to improve the script).

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green `H` icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)